# Go get workflow for forked repo

Tags: git, github, go

I am using [`apex`](https://github.com/apex/apex) and have installed it with `go get github.com/apex/apex/cmd/apex`. I have `$GOPATH/bin/apex` which works great. I wanted to make some contributions to apex, so I forked it and ran `go get github.com/ajcrites/apex/cmd/apex`. So far so good.

The problem comes when I want to actually test my local changes to the project. There are three issues I can see:

1. Running `go build` locally doesn't work because the `main.go` file imports directly from `$GOPATH/src/github.com/apex`. I need it to import from `$GOPATH/src/github.com/ajcrites` for the purposes of testing
2. Changing `main.go` manually to import from `ajcrites` is wonky since I can't/shouldn't commit these changes. Moreover even though it does build with my files -- I can tell because it lints them -- the binary that is emitted doesn't work at all.
3. Changing `$GOPATH/src/github.com/ajcrites` to `/apex` and building that way does work, but there are two issues:

   - The file system directory doesn't match the actual repo name which is weird
   - I still want to be able to use the actual binary from `/apex` without clobbering it just for the purposes of testing local changes

Is there a recommended way to clone forked `go` repositories and build/test locally?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the import paths in your code, or vendor the source in your project, don't change directory where the code lies in GOPATH. If you want to change the import path, you will need to rewrite that in all the source, or you end up importing multiple versions of the package.

Go into the `$GOPATH/src/github.com/apex/apex` directory and change the `origin` remote to your forked repo. By convention, I also add the original repo as an `upstream` remote, so I can conveniently fetch and merge changes from there as well.

Since vendoring is enabled by default since go1.6, you can put the source in a `vendor/` directory under your control, and make your modifications there. Using git submodules can also allow you to keep it under separate version control, but linked to your project.

Comment: When I do `go get github.com/ajcrites/apex/cmd/apex` the origin remote _is_ already set to `https://github.com/ajcrites/apex` (not ssh, another annoyance). This doesn't solve the issue -- I think it is an issue related to Go/Godeps and has nothing to do with git really.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: sorry, pasted the wrong URL in there. You want to keep the upstream path, so use `github.com/apex/apex`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: oh, and you didn't mention `godeps`. I don't use that very often, so there might be a better way to handle forks in that tool specifically. My recommendations were for go in general.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning `godeps`; I don't really know that much about go at this point and I thought godeps was pretty much standard. apex is using godeps though; I didn't choose to do that one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the flow I recommend and use for managing the Gorilla organization on GitHub:

```
$ go get github.com/gorilla/csrf
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/gorilla/csrf

# Alternatively, you can git remote remove origin + re-add as SSH
$ git remote add elithrar git@github.com:elithrar/csrf.git

$ git checkout -b new-feature-X
$ <do some work on it>

# Install those changes.
$ go install ./...
```

That's it. No need to change import paths in any existing programs. If you're vendoring the dependencies, you can just change it in the vendored copy.

Comment: Thanks; they don't recommend you use a fork? I think that this also doesn't really solve the problem of being able to test local changes while still keeping the stable binary installed.

Comment: You have two options: re-install the stable binary once done via `git checkout master && go install ./...` or alternatively you re-vendor that new branch into your project. Using forks means you have to re-write all of the URLs not just in your project, but also within any subpackages of the library you're trying to modify (as it might import its own helper libraries).